# JFreeChart implementation error

Tags: java, jfreechart

```
import java.io.*;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart; 
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities; 
public class xyLine {  
      public static void main(String[] args){
         try {

                /* Step - 1: Define the data for the line chart  */
                DefaultCategoryDataset line_chart_dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
                line_chart_dataset.addValue(15, "schools", "1970");
                line_chart_dataset.addValue(30, "schools", "1980");
                line_chart_dataset.addValue(60, "schools", "1990");
                line_chart_dataset.addValue(120, "schools", "2000");
                line_chart_dataset.addValue(240, "schools", "2010");                

                /* Step -2:Define the JFreeChart object to create line chart */
                JFreeChart lineChartObject=ChartFactory.createLineChart("Schools Vs Years","Year","Schools Count",line_chart_dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false);                

                /* Step -3 : Write line chart to a file */               
                 int width=640; /* Width of the image */
                 int height=480; /* Height of the image */                
                 File lineChart=new File("line_Chart_example.png");              
                 ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(lineChart,lineChartObject,width,height); 
         }
         catch (Exception i)
         {
             System.out.println(i);
         }
     }
 }
```

I am creating a line chart with points on it. The line that is causing problems is as follows...
JFreeChart lineChartObject=ChartFactory.createLineChart("Schools Vs Years","Year","Schools Count",line_chart_dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false);

The error is: The type org.jfree.util.PublicCloneable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have tried adding in the jar file(jfreechart-1.0.14.jar) but it still does not work. Anyone with any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably want to buy the developer guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `jcommon-1.0.14.jar` as well. See [*Downloading JFreeChart*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html) for more.